# C FFF mock redefinition

Tags: c, unit-testing, gcc, mocking, fake-function-framework

I'm trying to use the FFF mocking library for C (https://github.com/meekrosoft/fff) to unit test C code. The issue I'm running into is gcc is seeing my mock object as a redefinition of the original function and throwing compiler errors because of it.

I created 2 testing files that mimick my use cases. `my_lib.c` has definitions of some internal functions. `test.c` is importing `my_lib.c` because the intent is to test all the functions from the source file.

```
//my_lib.c

int thing = 0;

int get_thing () {
    return thing;
}

int do_thing (void) {
    return thing;
}

int set_thing (int x) {
    thing = x;
    return do_thing();
}
```

---

```
//test.c
#include "fff.h"
#include "my_lib.c"

DEFINE_FFF_GLOBALS;

FAKE_VALUE_FUNC0(int, do_thing);

void setup(void)
{
    // Reset the FFF call history between tests
    FFF_RESET_HISTORY();

    // Reset the FFF mock objects between tests
    RESET_FAKE(do_thing);
}

void test_do_thing(void)
{
    set_thing(11);

    ASSERT_EQ(1, do_thing_fake.call_count);
}

void test_nested_mock(void)
{
    do_thing_fake.return_val = -2;

    int ret = set_thing(11); //set_thing() returns do_thing() which is mocked to return -2

    ASSERT_EQ(-2, ret);
}
```

---

I'm compiling into an object file like so, but this gives me an immediate compilation error:

```
$ gcc -g -c test.c -o test.o
In file included from test.c:1:0:
test.c:7:23: error: redefinition of ‘do_thing’
 FAKE_VALUE_FUNC0(int, do_thing);
                       ^
fff.h:1632:45: note: in definition of macro ‘DEFINE_FAKE_VALUE_FUNC0’
     RETURN_TYPE FFF_GCC_FUNCTION_ATTRIBUTES FUNCNAME(void){ \
                                             ^
test.c:7:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘FAKE_VALUE_FUNC0’
 FAKE_VALUE_FUNC0(int, do_thing);
 ^
In file included from test.c:3:0:
my_lib.c:12:1: note: previous definition of ‘do_thing’ was here
 do_thing (void)
 ^
```

I need to be able to mock out functions from source files while being able to test legacy source files *without* modifying any source or header files. What am I missing with fff and/or gcc?

EDIT: Let me add this. I could remove the definition of do_thing() from `my_lib.c` and then my compilation, mocks, and tests work exactly as expected because all calls to do_thing now go to my mock object. I want to be able to mock a function that is already defined within the source code under test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer to your question depends on whether this function that you want to mock is a function you also want to test.

### Option 1:

If you only want to mock the function in your tests and not use its original implementation, then the solution is simple:

add the `weak` statement prior to the original function definition (in the c file). For example, with GCC you write: `__attribute((weak))` before the function definition.
Before:

```
void foo(void)
```

After:

```
__attribute((weak)) void foo(void)
```

This tells the compiler that if there is another definition for the same function in the code, then the one with the `weak` attribute is ignored.

In addition, if you don't want to change the source code you can add it in with `#ifdef UNIT_TEST_ENABLED` and make sure that the definition UNIT_TEST_ENABLED is defined only the unit test project and not in the production code project.
For example:

```
#ifdef UNIT_TEST_ENABLED 
__attribute((weak)) 
#endif 
void foo(void)
```

### Option 2:

If you want to use the original implementation in some of the tests but also be able to mock in other tests then I suggest you follow the instructions I wrote here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65814339/4441211